# Laravel Database Relationship

Tags: database, laravel, relationship

I'm trying to design an database using Laravel's relationships for a sports site. So far I've got 8 tables planned:

- Organization
- League
- Season
- Teams
- Roster
- Games
- Players
- Stats

Each Team belongs to and Organization and a League. Organizations and Leagues has many teams. This is because Organizations can have teams in different leagues.

After that I'm starting to run into questions. My plan is that the Games table will store Home and Away teams, so I think that's a has many relationship. Games also need to be part of a season and league so Games would belong to Season and League. Am I on track there?

Also, Players can belong to more then one Team during the same Season. That's why I did the Roster table do that Players can be linked with Teams and Seasons there. Plus I'm hoping that would be historical rosters by Season. I can't wrap my head around what relationships I need to pull this off.

Last would be Stats which would belongTo Games and Players and each player would have their own Stat row for each game played. Or would have be a has Many relationship?

Answer (score 0):

For Games, you can simply have a home_team_id and an away_team_id foreign key column to the Teams table; this would be two belongsTo relationships for Game and one hasMany relationship for Team.

As for Rosters, it sounds like a simple pivot table and a [belongsToMany relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many) between Players and Teams. Rosters would have: player_id, team_id, and season_id. For Player, Roster, and Team, you could have a maximum of two belongsToMany relationships each.